# Pickle persistence

Tags: python, persistence, pickle

I'm starting using Python recently and I'm trying to make a program that manipulates data in Python using `pickle`, however I would like my file to be kind like this:

```
             CODE | PIECE | PRICE
line one       1      1     1,00
line two       2      2     2,00
```

Consider 1 right down `CODE`, 1 right down `PIECE` and `1,00` right down `PRICE` until gets `50`.

Here's the question: Is there anyway to do this using pickle? Like:

```
columns = int(input('Number of columns : ')) # Which would be 3 (code, piece and price)
data = [ ]

for i in range(columns):
    raw = input('Enter data '+str(i)+' : ')
    data.append(raw)

file = open('file.dat', 'wb')
pickle.dump(data, file)
file.close()
```

Obviously, it cannot be done using input, so is there some way to do this?

Comment: Not with `pickle`. `pickle` is not meant to be read by people. Its a terse encoding understood by python. You may be thinking of a [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) file?

Comment: Also see the [Wiikipedia article on the CSV (Comma Separated Values)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file format. They're usually plain-text files and therefore somewhat "human readable".